# How to properly calculate width for D3 Siluohette stacked Area chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

Hopefully Mike Bostock comes swinging in to my rescue on this one.

(EDIT: With the help of Andrea Crawford's answer below this is the working version)
JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dfcarter/kd0dkrL8/

I have written a chart in d3 to allow on the fly user changes (colors, selected data, etc)

Well it is mainly working but when you remove the lower ordinals it stops centering on the graph and starts to creep downward.

**Looks Fine - removing the first 3 seems fine**
[image]

**Looks Unacceptable - removing the Last 3 and the chart is toward the bottom of the graph area**
[image]

The Core of the D3 for reference:

(The Fiddle works correctly I don't see why the external reference to spectrum is not working so look at the fiddle)

```js
var $pop = $('#my_custom_menu'),
  notHov = 1; // Hover flag

$pop.hover(function() {
  notHov ^= 1;
}); // Toggle flag on hover

$(document).on('mouseup keyup', function(e) {
  if (notHov || e.which == 27) $pop.fadeOut();
});

/////// CALL POPUP
$('.my_custom_menu').click(function() {
  $pop.stop().fadeIn();
});


function updateStream(color) {
  var label1 = d3.selectAll(".layer")
    .filter(function(d, i) {
      return i === clickIndex;
    })
    .style("fill", color);
}
$("#showPalette").spectrum({
  showPalette: true,
  palette: [
    ['black', 'white', 'blanchedalmond'],
    ['rgb(255, 128, 0);', 'hsv 100 70 50', 'lightyellow']
  ],
  change: updateStream
});

var clickIndex = 0;
$("#textDisplayName").keyup(function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    //alert(eval($("#stream").val) + " , " + eval($("#textDisplayname").val));
    var newValue = document.getElementById("textDisplayName").value;

    var label1 = d3.selectAll("text")
      .filter(function(d, i) {
        return i === clickIndex;
      })
      .text(newValue);

  }
});

chart("data.csv", "blue");

var datearray = [];
var colorrange = [];

function csv(url, callback) {
  d3.text(url, function(text) {
    callback(text && d3.csv.parse(text));
  });
}

function drawgrid() {

}


function chart(csvpath, color) {

  if (color == "blue") {
    colorrange = ["#045A8D", "#2B8CBE", "#74A9CF", "#A6BDDB", "#D0D1E6", "#F1EEF6"];
  } else if (color == "pink") {
    colorrange = ["#980043", "#DD1C77", "#DF65B0", "#C994C7", "#D4B9DA", "#F1EEF6"];
  } else if (color == "orange") {
    colorrange = ["#B30000", "#E34A33", "#FC8D59", "#FDBB84", "#FDD49E", "#FEF0D9"];
  }
  strokecolor = colorrange[0];

  var format = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%y");

  var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 40,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 30
  };
  var width = document.body.clientWidth - margin.left - margin.right - 200;
  var height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var tooltip = d3.select("body")
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", "remove")
    .style("position", "absolute")
    .style("z-index", "20")
    .style("visibility", "hidden")
    .style("top", "30px")
    .style("left", "55px");

  var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

  var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height - 10, 0]);

  var getColor = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(colorrange);

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(d3.time.weeks);

  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y);

  var yAxisr = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y);

  var stack = d3.layout.stack()
    .offset("silhouette")
    .values(function(d) {
      return d.values;
    })
    .x(function(d) {
      return d.date;
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return d.value;
    });

  var nest = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {
      return d.key;
    });

  var area = d3.svg.area()
    .interpolate("cardinal")
    .x(function(d) {
      return x(d.date);
    })
    .y0(function(d) {
      return y(d.y0);
    })
    .y1(function(d) {
      return y(d.y0 + d.y);
    });

  var svg = d3.select(".chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");





  function randomData() {
    return Math.random() * 9;
  }
  var dates = ["07/08/2016", "07/09/2016", "07/10/2016", "07/11/2016", "07/12/2016", "07/13/2016", "07/14/2016", "07/15/2016", "07/16/2016", "07/17/2016", "07/18/2016"];
  var numberOfSeries = 7,
    numberOfDataPoint = 7,
    data = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < numberOfSeries; ++i) {
    for (var j = 0; j < numberOfDataPoint; ++j) {
      data.push({
        key: i,
        value: randomData(),
        date: Date.parse(dates[j])

      });
    }
  }
  var layerData = nest.entries(data);
  var checkholder = d3.select("#checkboxHolder")
  var legend = checkholder.selectAll(".legend")
    .data(layerData)
    .enter().append("div")



  legend.append("input")
    .attr("type", "checkbox")
    .attr("id", function(d, i) {
      return "check" + i
    });


  legend.append("label")
    .attr("for", function(d, i) {
      return "check" + i
    })
    .attr("y", 9)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .html(function(d) {
      return d.key;
    });

  legend.on('change', function(d) {
    d.disabled = !d.disabled;

    d3.transition().duration(600).each(redraw);
  });

  var xaxisnode = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

  var yaxisnode = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + ", 0)")
    .call(yAxis.orient("right"));

  //svg.append("g")
  //    .attr("class", "y axis")
  //    .call(yAxis.orient("left"));
  function redraw() {
    var activeLayers = layerData.filter(function(d1) {
      return !d1.disabled;
    });
    var layers = stack(activeLayers);

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
      return d.date;
    }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
      if (!d.disabled) return d.y0 + d.y;
    })]);
    svg.selectAll(".layergroup").remove();

    var layergroup = svg.selectAll(".layergroup")
      .data(layers)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "layergroup");

    var paths = layergroup.append("path")
      .attr("class", "layer")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        return area(d.values);
      })
      .style("fill", function(d, i) {
        return getColor(i);
      });

    layergroup.append("text")
      .datum(function(d) {
        return {
          name: d.key,
          value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]
        };
      })
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.y0 + d.value.y / 2) + ")";
      })
      .attr("x", -6)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("class", "pathLabel")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
      });

    //var clickIndex = 0;
    //paths.on("click", function (d, i) {
    //    clickIndex = i;
    //    svg.selectAll("text").filter(function (d, i) { return i === clickIndex }).attr("transform", function (d) { var coords = d3.mouse(svg.node()); return "translate(" + coords[0] + "," + coords[1] + ")"; })
    //});


    xaxisnode.call(xAxis);
    yaxisnode.call(yAxis.orient("right"));

    const drag = d3.behavior.drag()
      .origin(function(d) {
        return d;
      })
      .on("dragstart", dragstarted)
      .on("drag", dragged)
      .on("dragend", dragended)

    function dragstarted(d) {
      d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
    }
    var dragIndex = 0;

    function dragged(d, i) {
      dragindex = i;
      const elem = svg.selectAll(".pathLabel").filter(function(d, i) {
        return i === dragindex;
      });
      elem.attr('transform', function(d) {
        var coords = d3.mouse(svg.node());
        return "translate(" + coords[0] + "," + coords[1] + ")";
      });
      //elem.attr('y', +elem.attr('y') + d3.event.dy)
    }

    function dragended(d) {}

    svg.selectAll(".layer")
      .attr("opacity", 1)
      .on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
        svg.selectAll(".layer").transition()
          .duration(250)
          .attr("opacity", function(d, j) {
            return j != i ? 0.6 : 1;
          })
      })

      .on("mousemove", function(d, i) {
        mousex = d3.mouse(this);
        mousex = mousex[0];
        var invertedx = x.invert(mousex);
        invertedx = invertedx.getMonth() + invertedx.getDate();
        var selected = (d.values);
        for (var k = 0; k < selected.length; k++) {
          datearray[k] = selected[k].date
          datearray[k] = datearray[k].getMonth() + datearray[k].getDate();
        }

        mousedate = datearray.indexOf(invertedx);
        pro = d.values[mousedate].value;
        mouse = d3.mouse(d3.select("#letable").node());
        d3.select(this)
          .classed("hover", true)
          .attr("stroke", strokecolor)
          .attr("stroke-width", "0.5px"),
          tooltip.html("<p>" + d.key + "<br>" + pro + "</p>").style("visibility", "visible").style("left", (mouse[0] + 50) + "px").style("top", (mouse[1] + 30) + "px");

      })
      .on("mouseout", function(d, i) {
        svg.selectAll(".layer")
          .transition()
          .duration(250)
          .attr("opacity", "1");
        d3.select(this)
          .classed("hover", false)
          .attr("stroke-width", "0px"), tooltip.html("<p>" + d.key + "<br>" + pro + "</p>").style("visibility", "hidden");
      })
      .on("contextmenu", function(data, index) {
        var position = d3.mouse(this);
        d3.select('#my_custom_menu')
          .style('position', 'absolute')
          .style('left', position[0] + "px")
          .style('top', position[1] + "px")
          .style('display', 'block');
        d3.event.preventDefault();

        //d3.select('#stream')
        //    .attr("value", index);
        clickIndex = index;
        $('#textDisplayName')
          .val(data.key);


      }).call(drag);



    //d3.select('svg')
    //    .selectAll('text')
    //    .data(labels)
    //    .enter()
    //    .append('text')
    //    .text(d => d)
    //    .attr('fill', 'green')
    //    .attr('x', (d, i) => 10 + i * 30)
    //    .attr('y', (d, i) => 15 + i * 30)
    //    .call(drag)

    var vertical = d3.select(".chart")
      .append("div")
      .attr("class", "remove")
      .style("position", "absolute")
      .style("z-index", "19")
      .style("width", "1px")
      .style("height", "380px")
      .style("top", "10px")
      .style("bottom", "30px")
      .style("left", "0px")
      .style("background", "#ccc");

    d3.select(".chart")
      .on("mousemove", function() {
        mousex = d3.mouse(d3.select("#letable").node());
        mousex = mousex[0] + 5;
        vertical.style("left", mousex + "px")
      })
      .on("mouseover", function() {
        mousex = d3.mouse(d3.select("#letable").node());
        mousex = mousex[0] + 5;
        vertical.style("left", mousex + "px")
      });

  }
  redraw();

}
```

```css
body {
  font: 10px "segoe ui";
}

.chart {
  background: #fff;
}

p {
  font: 12px "segoe ui";
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #CCC;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.pathLabel {
  font: bold 16px "Segoe UI";
  color: black;
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px #FFF;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 50px;
  top: 10px;
}

#my_custom_menu {
  display: none;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  width: 220px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px -2px #024;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/2.6.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>
  <script src="https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/spectrum.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v2.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/spectrum.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <table id="letable">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="checkboxHolder" style="width:200px;height:400px;overflow:auto;">

        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="chart" style="width:700px;height:400px">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div id="my_custom_menu">
    <input id="textDisplayName" type="text" />
    <br />
    <input id="showPalette" type="text" />
    <br />
    <input type="hidden" id="stream" value="" />
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @mbostock your are my only hope! haha.  I don't even know if @ works if they are not already on the question but worth a shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an expert on D3 so you may still want to wait for Mr. Bostock, but I think your issue is that inside your redraw function, you have this code:

```
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
  if (!d.disabled) return d.y0 + d.y;
})]);
```

but if you look at the value of d, it doesn't actually have a disabled property.

You could add a disabled property to the values at the same time you add it to the parent:

```
legend.on('change', function(d) {
    d.disabled = !d.disabled;
    $.each(d.values, function(){
        this.disabled = d.disabled;
    });
    d3.transition().duration(600).each(redraw);
});
```

There's probably a more elegant way to do that, but it seems to fix the issue.

Comment: You are my Michael Bostock for the day.  Thanks!